# How to modify a kernel based on what top-level recipe is being built using openembedded and bitbake?

Tags: bitbake, openembedded

I have two recipes that build an embedded linux image, call them `A.bb` and `B.bb`. I have a kernel patch that needs to be applied to one recipe but not the other. Following these [docs](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6.1/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#kernel-dev-common) I created my own layer and added a bbappend `<your-layer>/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_3.4.bbappend` and inside I put `SRC_URI|+="kernel.patch"`. How can I do something like the following:

```
if (A):
   SRC_URI+="kernel.patch"
else:
   SRC_URI+=""
```

## I tried the following:

Inside `A.bb`, I have `export IMAGE_NAME="A"`
Then inside `linux_yocto_3.4.bbappend` I have
`SRC_URI_append = " ${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_NAME', 'A', 'file://kernel.patch', '', d)} "`

But this doesn't work. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

A recipe can't influence how anything else is built; an image is just a recipe, thus is can't modify how the kernel is being built nor patched.